# C# Generating Delay Using Timer

Tags: c#, timer, delay

I'm trying to generate delay in my code using Timer. Interval is 10 milliseconds and my Elapsed function is `timer1_Tick` .The timer started and these are my functions:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (delay_ms != 0) 
        {
            delay_ms--;
        }
    }
    void Timer_Delay(uint delay)
    {
        delay_ms = delay;
        while (delay_ms != 0) ;
    }
```

My `timer1_Tick` works fine (tested), but in `Timer_Delay` function the code hangs in `while (delay_ms != 0) ;` line. It should pass this line after 1 second in `Timer_Delay(100)` right?
Here is an example using Timer delay instead of `Thread.sleep`

```
if (ROTOR_TIME_CONSTANT.BackColor.Equals(Color.Thistle))
            {
                do
                {
                    serialPort.Write("vA" + ROTOR_TIME_CONSTANT.Value + "*");
                    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
                    Timer_Delay(100);
                } while (ROTOR_TIME_CONSTANT.BackColor.Equals(Color.Thistle));
```

Comment: where are you changing the value of delay_ms within the while loop? because eventually it has to become 0 otherwise it wont stop...

Comment: timer1_Tick function decrease this value every 10 milliseconds

Comment: where do you call timer1_Tick ?

Comment: and where are you calling the Timer_Delay....?

Comment: timer1_Tick is my timer Elapsed function

Comment: if (ROTOR_TIME_CONSTANT.BackColor.Equals(Color.Thistle))
                {
                    do
                    {
                        serialPort.Write("vA" + ROTOR_TIME_CONSTANT.Value + "*");
                        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                        Timer_Delay(100);
                    } while (ROTOR_TIME_CONSTANT.BackColor.Equals(Color.Thistle));

Comment: @MohammadFarahi edit your question and post the code there.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Thread.Sleep(delayInMilliseconds)` instead. Check out for the documentation [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep(v=vs.110).aspx)

### Update

If you want to use the timer you can use a [**EventWaitHandle**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
    EventWaitHandle ewh;
    uint delay_ms;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (delay_ms != 0)
        {
            delay_ms--;

            if(delay_ms == 0)
            {
                ewh.Set();
            }
        }
    }
    void Timer_Delay(uint delay)
    {
        ewh = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);
        delay_ms = delay;
        ewh.WaitOne();
    }
```

### Update 2

This will not work in a WinForms environment using [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx), because it runs on the same thread of the UI. So if you block the thread of the UI, your timer will never tick. If you still want to use a timer, you can use [System.Timers.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx), which is more accurate and operates on a separate thread, but this way you are blocking the UI until the delay has passed, because you are blocking its thread.
If you need to wait, you can create a separate thread first and run your processes there, so if you pause the thread, the UI remains responsive.

Comment: Thanks for your respond but in the question mentioned using Timer

Comment: @MohammadFarahi I have updated the answer, check it out :)

Comment: It can't work using a System.Windows.Forms.Timer, because it's single-threaded... It uses the same thread of the UI, so if you block the thread of the UI, the timer won't tick anymore. If you still want to use a timer, you can use the code above with System.Timers.Timer, which is more accurate and operates on a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

Timer's tick event is raised on UI thread. You are blocking UI thread with endless loop:

```
while (delay_ms != 0)
```

so the Timer will never tick.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to temporarily stop the timer and start it up again, you can consider the following:

```
async Task Timer_Delay(uint delay)
{
    timer.Stop();
    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(delay);
    timer.Start();
}
```

You can call this from an asynchronous method using:

```
await Timer_Delay(5000);
```

**Edit**

Using `await Timer_Delay(5000);` from a method declared as `async` will hold execution for however many milliseconds you specify (in this case 5000) but will not have the same effect as `Thread.Sleep` where it blocks the main thread.

This will pause execution within the method it is called from *until* the timer starts up again (as shown in the `Timer_Delay` method above.

Comment: Can you explain more about using await Timer_Delay(5000);?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right you can use Timer class.

```
 public Timer(TimerCallback callback, object state, int dueTime, int period);
```

For example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Where Hello is a callback, null will be send as an argument to Hello method
        //2000 is a delay in milliseconds, Timeout.Infinite is periodic of calling a method
        Timer timer = new Timer(Hello, null, 2000,Timeout.Infinite);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Hello(Object o)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

For more information please refer to this topic:https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Kordik's got the relevant post.  You've got a thread in the UI that, when it's churning away, will destroy your timer ticks.  Take this simple code:

```
int x = 0;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    x++;
    textBox1.Text = x.ToString();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

    while ((DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds < 4)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

... when you click the button, the timer will stop going off for four seconds (and it won't retroactively trigger the events, either.)

Instead of fighting this problem, by arranging asynchronous waits and stuff like that?  Have the GUI kick off a separate thread for your processing.  Whatever user interaction or system event or whatever kicks off this whole big function that does this BackColor check?  Have it kicked off in a separate thread, and you bypass this problem (and all sorts of other problems like non-responsiveness.)

... or failing that, include some variety of Application.DoEvents() in your main loop.  That will let the UI threads still keep processing the tick events.  (adding Application.DoEvents() beside the System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10) in my example will make the timer continue working.