# How to have program wait X seconds and allow UI to execute?

Tags: c#, timer, wait

I am making a small game with an auto play feature, but the program runs too fast so the user can't see the outcome at each stage. I am using VS 2017, so I can't use async (at least from what I have read). How can I have the program wait and allow the UI to update?

I am working in a do while loop. The main chunk of the game executes, updates the UI, and then waits for the player to click a button (assuming auto play is not running), with auto play running the do while loop repeats, but after the UI updates it would wait X seconds.

Comment: `I am using VS 2017, so I can't use async`, why ?

Comment: This may help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458118/wait-one-second-in-running-program?rq=1)

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372355/how-can-i-perform-a-short-delay-in-c-sharp-without-using-sleep

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like you have a couple of options

1.You can try Sleep -(but it may hang the UI)

```
 int Seconds = 1;
 Threading.Thread.Sleep(Seconds * 1000);
```

2.You can try this code:

```
int Seconds = 1;
Private void WaitNSeconds(int seconds)
    { 
       if (seconds < 1) return;
         DateTime _desired = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds);
         while (DateTime.Now < _desired) {
              System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
         }
     }
```

3.Try to use Async and see what happens

```
async Task MakeDelay() {
      await Task.Delay(5000); 
}   
private async void btnTaskDelay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      await MakeDelay();          
}
```

Comment: So it turns out async should work with VS 2017, but I can't just do the await Task.Delay(ms), and the API is terrible. However, the DateTime timer works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use a [`Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) component instead of a loop, and put the loop body in the timer's `Elapsed` event.

And VS2017 *definitely* supports `async`, but it wouldn't help in this case... things would still move too fast for the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use async/await to slow down the execution of event handler without having to split the logic. This is pretty simple:

```
async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // wpf event handler
{
    ...
    await Task.Delay(1000); // pause 1 second
    ...

    while (someCondition)
    {
        ...
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        ...
    }
}
```

You can read about `async`/`await` at [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443(vs.110).aspx).

If you are using WPF, then you have to look into [animations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/animation-overview). They are much simpler to use to ensure smooth changes than manually changing something (position, sizes).

Answer (score 0):

Usage: DelayFactory.DelayAction(500, new Action(() => { this.RunAction(); }));`

//Note Forms.Timer and Timer() have similar implementations. 
//Assumes you will have a DelayFactory Static Class

```
public static void DelayAction(int millisecond, Action action)
{
    var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Tick += delegate

    {
        action.Invoke();
        timer.Stop();
    };

    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(millisecond);
    timer.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait function using timers, no UI locks.

```
public void wait(int milliseconds)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    if (milliseconds == 0 || milliseconds < 0) return;
    //Console.WriteLine("start wait timer");
    timer1.Interval = milliseconds;
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Start();
    timer1.Tick += (s, e) =>
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        timer1.Stop();
        //Console.WriteLine("stop wait timer");
    };
    while (timer1.Enabled)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
wait(1000); //wait one second
```